# What is the difference between using `new classObject` and `&classObject` when creating a new object?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, new-operator

Below is my code, in which I defined two classes `Node` and `List` that do what you think they do. While extending the list, I need to create a new Node object (see **the line with comment in my code**). If I use `new Node(data)` then everything seems fine and the output is

```
2 3 5
```

But if I change it to `&Node(data)`, the output becomes

```
7530648 7530648 7530648 7530648 7530648 7530648 7530648 7530648 7530648 7530648 7530648 7530648
7530648 7530648 7530648 7530648 7530648 7530648 7530648 7530648 7530648 7530648 7530648 7530648
```

(and so on; doesn't end unless I close the window)

What is the difference between using `new Node(data)` and `&Node(data)` here? Why is the output of the second case so weird?

**Note that I used the -fpermissive option for my TDM-GCC-64-5.1.0 compiler.** While this seems like a bad choice, I just realized what I am actually unsure of is how long the Node object created by the expression `Node(data)` lives. So hopefully this question will still be useful to those who might have the same confusion.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
    int _data;
    Node* _next;
public:
    Node(int data) { _data = data; _next = 0; }
    void setNext(Node* next) { _next = next; }
    Node* getNext() const { return _next; }
    int getData() const { return _data; }
};

class List
{
    Node* _head;
public:
    List() { _head = 0; }
    void add(int data)
    {
        if(!_head)
        {
            _head = new Node(data);
            return;
        }
        Node* temp = _head;
        while(temp->getNext())
            temp = temp->getNext();
        temp->setNext(new Node(data)); // What if I use `&Node(data)` instead of `new Node(data)`?
    }
    void print() const
    {
        Node* temp = _head;
        while(temp)
        {
            cout<<temp->getData()<<" ";
            temp = temp->getNext();
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    List L;
    L.add(2);
    L.add(3);
    L.add(5);
    L.print();
}
```

Comment: `&Node(data)` won't compile.

Comment: What compiler are you using? And do you have your warnings turned on?

Comment: "*What if I use `&Node(data)` instead of `new Node(data)`?*" You get a compile error.

Comment: `_next = next;` has a const correctness error and should also not compile. You are assigning a `const Node*` to a `Node*`.

Comment: Probably because I used the -fpermissive option for my compiler, the compiler is g++ from TDM-GCC-64-5.1.0 @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: @ihdv That's a huge mistake. Basically anything it allows won't work as intended as you've seen here.

Comment: Needless to say, don't use `-fpermissive`.

Comment: Better enable all possible warnings while developing. You cannot do `&Node(adfgadf)` because the newly created object is immediately destroyed. or "error: taking address of temporary" as my compiler says

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference between using `new classObject` and `&classObject`

`new classObject` Creates a new object of type `classObject` with dynamic storage.

`&classObject` returns the address of the object named by the identifier `classObject`.

> ```
> &Node(data)
> ```

This expression is ill-formed. The operand of the addressof operator is an rvalue here. That is not allowed. A compiler is not required to succesfully compile the program, and the standard does not describe how the program should behave. Here is example output from a compiler chosen at random:

```
error: taking the address of a temporary object of type 'Node' [-Waddress-of-temporary]
        temp->setNext(&Node(data));
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Some compilers do allow this as a language extension however. In such case this creates a temporary object of type `Node`. The lifetime of the temporary lasts until the end of that full expression. The addressof operator is applied on the temporary and the result is a pointer to the temporary. After the full expression, the pointer value will be invalid.

Attempting to access the temporary outside of its lifetime through the invalid pointer will have undefined behaviour.

> Why is the output of the second case so weird?

Because the behaviour of the program is undefined.

---

> ```
> Node* _next;
> void setNext(const Node* next) { _next = next; }
> ```

A pointer to const is not implicitly convertible to a pointer to non-const. This is also ill-formed. Here is example output from a compiler chosen at random:

```
error: assigning to 'Node *' from incompatible type 'const Node *'
    void setNext(const Node* next) { _next = next; }
                                             ^~~~
```

Comment: "lasts until the end of that full expression" If I am understanding correctly, `temp->setNext(&Node(data));` first creates a temporary Node object, takes its address and sends the address to `setNext`, and the object will be destroyed right after everything in `setNext` is executed?

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I feel confused about.

Answer (score 2):

`new Node(data)` and `&Node(data)` are similar from a certain
point of view because they both are a pointer to a `Node`.
In the first case this `Node` is dynamically allocated and should
be explicitly `delete`d one day or another.
In the second case you take the address (`&`) of a temporary `Node`
that will automatically disappear in a near future; this leads to
using a dangling pointer (and a decent compiler should prevent from
making this mistake).
Then in this second case your algorithm uses invalid data; thus the
weird display.
(all these temporary nodes seem to be located at the same place in
memory -- one after each other -- then your algorithms loops endlessly
over the same one)